# vacuum fails with ERROR: cannot freeze committed xmax

Tags: postgresql, data-corruption

Running Postgres 10.4 on CentOS

`VACUUM` fails with:

```
ERROR:  cannot freeze committed xmax <xxxxxxx>
```

The first time I found this error was 7 days ago

I checked 3 things:

- Long-running transactions: (none)
- Abandoned replication slots: (killed session for physical replication and even for logical)
- Orphaned prepared transactions: (Didn't find any)

I would appreciate any piece of advice.

Comment: [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/202690/postgresql-error-cannot-freeze-committed-xmax) might help :)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me at.. but that issue was related to confirmed bug in 9.4 for mat view and similar bug fixed in 9.6 (pg_upgrade utility related). In my case we have this issue on brand new cluster and on tables not mat views :(

Comment: Just restored a basebackup on another host and got the same ERROR:  cannot freeze committed xmax. So, data corruption confirmed. PS: Filed a bug with Postgres

Comment: Managed to restore physical backup and got the same error. Looks like I faced a bug.